# How to load html after commit Ajax form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I use a ajax form like this :

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Commit", "Product", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",

}))
{
}
```

and this code shows a list in a paartial view page:

```
<div class="containerHeadline" id="productlistview">

    @{
        Html.RenderAction(MVC.BaseInfo.Product.GetProductList());
    }
</div>
```

and this onsuccess function :

```js
        function OnSuccess() {

            $('#PopupModel').modal("hide");
     
            
        }
```

Now ,I want load html productlistview div that is updated now,to be displayed.

I want Something like this :

```js
  $('#productlistview').load();
```

Comment: Are you using modal?

Comment: yes.I use modal and I want show list after modal is hide.

Comment: so you already have a page that displays the list?

Comment: yes .I load list on a partial view page

Comment: checkout my answer dude

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using `JavascriptResult`.

`return JavaScript("window.location = 'http://listpage.com'");`

Or just refresh your current page.

`return JavaScript("location.reload(true)");`

Answer (score 0):

if you need to reload a page you have to use below code

```
 window.location.reload();
```

if you want to reload a particular , You have to use below code
    **In jquery**

```
$("selector / classname / Id").load(window.location + " selector / classname / Id");
```